# Get 2to3 to Use Spaces not Tabs

Tags: python, python-2to3

I used `2to3` to convert a folder of python modules. Everything went smooth, but when I went to run some of them it gave me an error about spaces and tabs. My theory: when `2to3` changes a line it uses tabs and not spaces unlike the rest of the non-changed lines. I was wondering if there was a way to change this.

The error is:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

The code snippet is difficult to show because a tab is shown equivalent to 4 spaces, but I checked and this was happening.

Comment: Could you show the specific error - and a snippet of code relating to that area of a file?

Comment: Please do include the error message you got. Are you saying your input files had only tabs and 2to3 used spaces for indentation, causing the end result to be mixed?

Comment: python -tt" & reindent.py

Comment: My original used spaces and 2to3 used tabs

Comment: It's extremely, extremely, extremely hard to believe that 2to3 actually *inserted* tabs. Spaces have been **overwhelmingly** preferred over tabs in the Python community since almost forever, long before there was even the idea to make a Python 3. So the idea that a tool *provided with the official Python*, and *written by developers of the official Python* would actually go against this is practically incomprehensible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2to3` should not replace white space with tabs so I am guessing that you get a `TabError` because those tabs where already present in the code and python 3 does not allow mixing tabs and spaces within a single file whereas that is fine in python 2.

This can be fixed using the `reindent.py` script that comes with python and can be found in linux systems under `/usr/lib/python2.7/Tools/scripts/reindent.py` or optionally can be installed using pip by `pip install reindent`. Then the command to replace tabs with spaces is:

```
reindent.py file.py
```